# For loop giving the same value for the entire column

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am new to python and trying to run a for loop. I am trying to multiply any value in a column that is greater than 20 with .25 and anything greater than 5 with .15 and create a new column with that values. This is what I am doing but I get the same values for the entire column:

```py
new_data = data[['restaurant_name', 'cost_of_the_order']].copy()

for x in new_data['cost_of_the_order']:
    if x > 20:
        data['revenue'] = x*.25 
        if x > 15 and x < 20:
            data['revenue'] = x*.15
```

I get this:

```
   restaurant_name         cost_of_the_order    revenue
0   Hangawi                        30.75        6.305
1   Blue Ribbon Sushi Izakaya      12.08        6.305
2   Cafe Havana                    12.23        6.305
3   Blue Ribbon Fried Chicken      29.20        6.305
4   Dirty Bird to Go               11.59        6.305
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed a bit you code mainly because I didn't know what that data[ ] is.
This is my solution:

```
import numpy as np

cost_of_the_order = [30.75, 12.8, 12.23, 29.20, 11.59]
restaurant_name = ['Hangawi', 'Blue Ribbon', 'Cafe Havana', 'Blue Ribbon 2', 'Birty Bird']
new_data = ['restaurant_name', 'cost_of_the_order'].copy()

revenue = []
for i in cost_of_the_order:
    if 5 < i < 20:
        revenue.append(i*.15)
    elif i > 20:
        revenue.append(i*.25)

np.hstack(revenue)
    
for x,y,z in zip(restaurant_name, cost_of_the_order, revenue):
        print (x ,y ,z)
```

The output is:

```
Hangawi 30.75 7.6875
Blue Ribbon 12.8 1.92
Cafe Havana 12.23 1.8345
Blue Ribbon 2 29.2 7.3
Birty Bird 11.59 1.7385
```

I used a list to get all the results of the for loop and then we get the output as an array with numpy.
The last `for loop` isn't necessary, it could be used to make a similar output as yours, but u could even use `pandas`.

Hope this solve your problem